# How to solve a CORS error that cannot be solved with a browser extension?

Tags: amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, .net-core, cors, aws-amplify

I have a working React application with a working backend made with .NET Core. I have experienced a CORS issue. Errors where clearly logged. Initially, I  "solved" the problem by using a chrome extension ([this one](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/moesif-origin-cors-change/digfbfaphojjndkpccljibejjbppifbc?hl=en-US)) as explained [here](https://medium.com/@dtkatz/3-ways-to-fix-the-cors-error-and-how-access-control-allow-origin-works-d97d55946d9).

Later on, I tried a better alternative, [allowing CORS via code in my .NET Core application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-5.0#cors-with-named-policy-and-middleware). This solved my problem. My react application (using localhost:3000) was able to use the backend (localhost:5000). The extensions was not needed anymore.

Logically, I was really happy everything worked fine. However, after putting my application in the Cloud (AWS Amplify for frontend, EKS for backend) problems appeared. Even my extension did not help solving it. Apparently, I have a different kind of CORS problem when using AWS Amplify instead of localhost.

This is a problem that even the extension does not solve (and neither does not code). Logically, it is not directly a problem that my extension does not help me. However, it shows that I simply have a different kind of CORS problem.

What different kind of CORS problem do I have as the extension does not solve it?

And how to solve this problem?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I can't see any code, what you have done. Try to google or search  stackoverflow. You will find thousands answers to start. If you have problem after this, then let us know.

Comment: @Serge As explained in my post, I already googled and found really useful blogs and and docs. I also referred to those sources with links. This solves my problem almost completely. Almost, just when  using AWS Amplify, it does not work for me.

Comment: Pls post what you have now already. This way you will not get the same code as answer again. Cors is very tricky, one line can change everytning.

Comment: @Serge The sources I referred to are from a google search. These sources have shown to be really useful and almost (!!) solve my problem. It works fine, except when running in AWS Amplify. Then it does not. How come? And how to solve? . I also referred to the code I copied from the microsoft docs.

Comment: Whether the header returned when running in AWS Amplify is normal.https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Startup.cs file in the NetCore project, go to Configure section and add:

```
app.UseCors(builder =>
      {
         builder.SetIsOriginAllowedToAllowWildcardSubdomains()
           .WithOrigins("http://example.com") //Put your React app url here
           .AllowAnyHeader()
           .AllowAnyMethod()
           .AllowCredentials();
        });
```

It worked for me in the same situation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `content-type` header to your CORS policy:

```
  builder.WithOrigins("http://example.com")
                           .WithHeaders(HeaderNames.ContentType) // Add your allowed headers here
                           .WithMethods("PUT", "DELETE", "GET", "OPTIONS");
```

Checkout the [Microsoft CORS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-5.0#set-the-allowed-request-headers)